# Автоматизация тестирования Eclipse

Tags: java

Здравсвуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, создаем автоматические тесты в среде Eclipse. Есть следующий фрагмент кода:

```
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys(login);
driver.findElement(By.id("passwd")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("passwd")).sendKeys(password);
```

Переменные login и password заданы. Как можно сделать так чтобыэти переменные не задавать в коде, а брать из файла, например txt?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Прочитал заголовок. Прочитал текст. Долго пытался связать одно с другим... А ещё больше не понял, при чём тут Eclipse и зачем его автоматически тестировать?

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать стандартный класс [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

## Формат текстового файла

```
login = bob
passwd = qwerty
...
```

## Считывание данных

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(new File(…)));
String login = props.getProperty("login"));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

У джавы есть как минимум два класса для работы с файлами. Scanner , BufferReader.
Создаешь файл считываешь значение из файла с помощью этих классов.
Используешь значение.